# An exception of type 'System.InvalidOperationException' occurred in System.Core.dll but was not handled in user code

Tags: c#, html, css, razor, asp.net-mvc-5

I am having a hard time solving this error. This error occurs whenever i'm logging in the login page.

the error is:
An exception of type 'System.InvalidOperationException' occurred in System.Core.dll but was not handled in user code

Additional information: Sequence contains no elements

here's the code:

```
     public ActionResult Login(UserAccount user)
    {
        using (OurDbContext db = new OurDbContext())
        {
            var usr = db.userAccount.Single(u => u.Username == user.Username && u.Password == user.Password);
            if (usr != null)
            {
                Session["UserID"] = usr.UserID.ToString();
                Session["Username"] = usr.Username.ToString();
                return RedirectToAction("LoggedIn");
            }
            else
            {
                ModelState.AddModelError("", "Username or Password is wrong.");
            }

        }
        return View();
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is the call to `Single`. When you use this method, your result set must contain *exactly one* entry. If you expect it to be empty, use `SingleOrDefault`.